# How to run the maven plugin via cmd in the root directory without running this plugin in all modules?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

We have a plugin that needs to be run via cmd, for example:

```
mvn com.test.plugins:some-plugin:2.1.0:generate
```

There is a root pom.xml, which has 3 modules

```
<modules>
    <module>first</module>
    <module>second</module>
    <module>third</module>
</modules>
```

And when the plugin is launched in this way from the root directory, the plugin is launched 4 times, in each module.
I know that if you were writing the plugin configuration in pom.xml

```
<build><plugins><plugin>
```

we can use the tag

```
<inherited>false</inherited>
```

How can I do this through the console?
Or maybe we can add something to the Mojo class of the plugin?

Comment: you mean to run that plugin only in the root module? If you call it from command line the plugin has to do that correctly...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running a maven plugin only in the parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041033/running-a-maven-plugin-only-in-the-parent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the -N (or --non-recursive) command line parameter:

```
mvn -N com.test.plugins:some-plugin:2.1.0:generate
```